ASP.NET_SessionId cookie being set too late for TempData to work
We are using TempData in an ASP.NET MVC website to transmit success messages around the place, however we have discovered that setting TempData["message"] does not work as expected the first time.
Instead of TempData["message"] being available as part of the next response, we are finding that the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie is being set after setting TempData the first time.
All subsequent usages of TempData work as expected.
Is there something we can do to eagerly populate this ASP.NET_SessionId cookie so that TempData will always work?

You can access session state explicitly at the beginning of the request like using basecontroller which can lead to initialize  the session state and set the sessionId cookie before tempData accessed
public class BaseController: Controller
{
    var session = HttpContext.Session;
}

then inherit this controller
public class TodoController:BaseController
{
   public IActionResult DoSomething()
   {
       Tempdata["message"]="Welcome Todo";
       return view();
   }    
}


Unfortunately this didn't work!
